# How to pass data to BusinessObject in stimulsoft report?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I need to pass data for stimulsoft report file via code.

```
public ActionResult PackageCommandPrint(string startDate, string endDate, int profileId)
    {
        try
        {
            List<PackageCommand> commands = new List<PackageCommand>();
            StiReport report = new StiReport();
            report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/PackageCommand.mrt"));
            if (HttpContext.Cache["PackageCommands"] == null)
            {
                using (SPMSEntities db = new SPMSEntities())
                {
                    commands = db.PackageCommands.ToList();
                    HttpContext.Cache.Insert("PackageCommands", commands, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                commands = HttpContext.Cache["PackageCommands"] as List<PackageCommand>;
            }
            string userFullName;
            using (SPMSEntities db = new SPMSEntities())
            {
                Profile profile = db.Profiles.Find(profileId);
                userFullName = profile.FirstName + " " + profile.LastName;
            }
            report.Dictionary.Variables.Add(new StiVariable("Params", "TodayPersianDate", Convertor.ToPersianDate(DateTime.Now)));
            report.Dictionary.Variables.Add(new StiVariable("Params", "UserFullName", userFullName));
            report.RegBusinessObject("Data", commands);                                                                                                      
            report.Compile();
            return StiMvcViewer.GetReportSnapshotResult(report);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HelperStoreSqlLog.WriteError(e, "PackageCommand");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Report file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A8CLRYAoIQNXPVJkqNucrxJeW1yxJFg1/view?usp=sharing

When i try to get report get me error that :

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   value at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult) at System.Enum.Parse(Type
>   enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase) at
>   Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.StiMvcViewer.SaveReportObjec t(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, StiReport report) at
>   Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.StiMvcViewer.GetReportSnapsh otResult(StiReport
>   report) at SPMS.Controllers.ReportController.PackageCommandPr
>   int(String startDate, String endDate, Int32 profileId) in
>   D:\Projects\SPMS\SPMS\Controllers\ReportController .cs:line 83

line 83 : `return StiMvcViewer.GetReportSnapshotResult(report);`

What is problem? I try to test this code by empty report file but get up error again.
[image]

Razor :

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc  
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(new StiMvcViewerOptions()
{
    Localization = "~/Content/Reports/Localization/fa.xml",
    Theme = StiTheme.Office2013,
    ActionGetReportSnapshot = "PackageCommandPrint",
    ActionViewerEvent = "PackageCommandViewer",
    ServerCacheMode = StiCacheMode.None 
})
```

Comment: Remove `report.Compile();`  must be correct

Comment: Dont work . Get up error again

Comment: I testyour report and it was okay.this is my code:  `StiReport report = new StiReport();
            report.Load(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Reports", "PackageCommand.mrt"));
            var data = new { };
            report.RegBusinessObject("Data", data);
            return StiNetCoreViewer.GetReportResult(this, report);`

Answer (score 1):

Add new Business Object (your model 'Data') **without Category**.
[image]

[image]

if you want to keep the category you should use this code

```
  //report.RegBusinessObject("category", "name", businessObject);
  report.RegBusinessObject("Data", "Data", commands);
```